# Cannot connect to WebSocket Server. No idea why

Tags: c#, html, debugging, connection, websocket

I'm using the code from [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/57060/Web-Socket-Server) article just to try and get something up and running. However, I cannot seem to connect to the web sockets server once it's running.

I have tried forwarding both ports 8080 and 8181, ensuring that they are forwarded using [canyouseeme](http://canyouseeme.org/), allowing the ports under my firewall, completely disabling my firewall, trying and forwarding different ports, etc.

Nothing has worked so far. Both the HTML browser page and console server application run just fine with no errors but I keep getting this error message when I try to connect through the HTML page in my browser:

```
Connecting to ws://localhost:8181/chat ...
Socket closed!
```

I have never used WebSockets before so I'm not sure if I'm missing something like if I need to install some framework, run some daemon, or what. I'm running Windows 7 64 Bit and using Visual Studio to run the solution. Not sure how to get this to work. Anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The server mentioned in that article is likely using the older Hixie protocol. If you are running a recent version of Chrome or Firefox then you are using the newer HyBi/IETF protocol.  The article was written in Jun 2010 before the newer protocol was standardized and adopted.

**Update**:

[Fleck](https://github.com/statianzo/Fleck) looks like a descendant of the code in that article (via [Nugget](http://nugget.codeplex.com/)) that supports the old and new protocol variants.

Comment: Oh.. Okay. Do you know where I can find an up-to-date WebSockets server example using C#?